# Representing time complexity recursively of recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

[image: function(A,p,r)]

Let () denote the time complexity of function(A, 1, n) where the size of array A is n.

I'm tryng to represent () recursively.

This is my solution and please check if I'm right.

The base part is `() = c (1>=n)`

In recursive part I think funtion(A,p,q) -> `(⌊(n+1)/2⌋)`.

But I have no idea about function(A,q+1,r)...

Tell me how can I solve it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you said `function(A, p, q)` --> `T[(n+1)/2]`, then `function(A, q+1, r)` is also `T[(n)/2]`.
The recursive equation will be `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(1)` Now you can use Master's theorem to solve the above recurrence

Comment: @risingStark Can you explain? I can't understand... You mean `function(A,p,q)` is `(⌊(n+1)/2⌋)` then `function(A,q+1,r)` is `(⌊(n)/2⌋)`??

Comment: It does not matter whether `function(A, q+1, r)` is `T(n/2)` or `T((n+1)/2)`. When writing recursive equations for calculating time complexities, these small constants and details does not matter. You just need to understand that your function just calls two other functions each half in size of the parent function.

Comment: @risingStark Oh, I see. Really thanks for your help!!